# Solve the next differential system using differential equation of higher order

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Ok, so i have the next differential system($x=x(t)$):
$$x'_1=-7x_1+x_2$$
$$x'_2=-x_1-5x_2$$
This is how I got an differential equation of higher order using this system: from the first equation I got $x_2$ and $x'_2$
$$x_2=x'_1+7x_1=>x'_2=x''_1+7x'_1$$
Than I introduced it into the 2nd equation and got this:
$$x''_1+12x'_1+36x_1=0$$
Than I rewrote that equation into an 
characteristic equation and solved it:
$$\lambda^2+12\lambda+36\lambda^0=0=>\lambda_{1,2}=-6$$ and the order multiplicity is 2(I don't know if I am right here, correct me if I am wrong). So $x_1(t)=e^{-6t}$ and $x_2(t)=te^{-6t}$.
In the end I get $$x(t)=c_1e^{-6t}+c_2te^{-6t}$$

But, and now comes the interesting part. I have this limit and don't know if I should prove it or get $c_1$ and $c_2$ from it(to prove it seems siple, only appling L'Hospital, but on the other hand I don't know how to use it to get $c_1$ and $c_2$). The limit is:
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}(x_1(t);x_2(t))=(0;0)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prove it and nothing else, because it won't determine any constant (obviously, because you proved its validity for every values $c_1,c_2$).